# Chinese character setting in putty not work

Tags: linux, putty

I need to display Chinese in putty and open a file in Chinese.

As others mentioned,
`1. locale setting ( LANG=zh_TW.big5 / LC_ALL=zh_TW.big5 )
2. Putty > Changed Setting > Translation > Remote(UTF-8) > Treat CJK[v]
3. Appearance > Change.. > Font(MingLiu) / Script(Chinese Big5)`

However, I can't make my putty available to read Chinese or Write it.

Is there any other configuration that I need to do more??

Thank you.

Comment: Solved. Changed locale to "zh_TW.UTF-8".
Anyone knows how to add another translation setting in putty??

Comment: You can use any language, but you must set UTF-8 for that.